# What is ISCAS85 benchmark?

Tags: digital-logic

What is ISCAS85 benchmark? I find it in a [paper about BDD optimization](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.71.1651&rep=rep1&type=pdf), is there any simulator for it?

Comment: Can you give us links to what you already know? Many people here can quickly dig through those things because of previous experience, but give us links to what it is!

Comment: I added the link to the document

Answer (score 6):

I'm writing a paper on the history of the benchmark circuits, and so found this question. Here is the story.
The ISCAS'85 benchmarks were collected and published to help in comparing automatic test generation (ATPG) tools. They were presented at the 1985 International Symposium on Circuits & Systems. At ISCAS'89 a set of sequential circuit benchmark circuits were presented to spur the development of sequential ATPG. (I was on the ISCAS'89 panel.) These are often used in combinational form, with all internal flops made into pseudo-primary inputs and outputs.
In 1999 I collected another set of benchmarks, a bit larger and more complex, and presented them in a panel at the International Test Conference. These are called the ITC'99 benchmarks. I also co-edited a special issue of IEEE Design & Test of Computers (now just IEEE Design & Test) on the benchmarks.
I was unaware they were also used for synthesis.
The circuits are available on line - Googling ISCAS85, ISCAS89 or ITC99 will lead to many writeups and papers. 
Scott Davidson

Comment: Do you have an update about this. Did you finish your paper?. Most current document i found is [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/23b4/782bd8fa6393a59526609152699b84658756.pdf), though i am sure there should be a newer updated source. In particular for Analog Mixed Signal. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [set of reference circuits](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece543/iscas85.html) that can be used to benchmark a synthesis tool. Since they aren't in VHDL or Verilog, you likely should convert them before simulating with a modern tool.

Comment: Can you please give us a reference to what you are saying? (although it seems quite reasonable).
I am also looking at the ISCAS benchmark. All I found out is this: "The ISCAS '85 benchmark circuits are ten combinational networks provided to authors at the
1985 International Symposium on Circuits And Systems." from: http://ddd.fit.cvut.cz/prj/Benchmarks/iscas85.pdf. However I am still not sure what are they bench-marking exactly and when am I suppoed to use them. What @Biran says seems reasonable. You use it to benchmark a "synthesis tool"